# unexpected '[', expecting ')' - array in constructor

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
class foo
{
    public function __construct
    (
        $bar[var1]  = 0,
        $bar[var2]  = 0,
        $bar[var3]  = 0
    )
    {
        /* do something */
    }
}
```

and I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in *$this* on line 5

and I have no idea about whats wrong.

**EDIT:**

I want to initialize the class like this: `$instance = new foo($bar)`
($bar is an array)

Because the class would expect many arguments, and I can easily return the array from the constructor.
Let me know if this is not a good idea.

Comment: this being the **EXACT** method of giving space in actual code?

Comment: What are you trying to do? For instance, how are you planning to call this function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why are you trying to create an array in the function argument definition? That makes no sense and you cannot do this.

If you want `$bar` to be an argument but ensure some values exist (i.e. default values), do it like this:

```
public function __construct($bar)
{
    if(!isset($bar['var1'])) $bar['var1'] = 0;
    if(!isset($bar['var2'])) $bar['var2'] = 0;
    if(!isset($bar['var3'])) $bar['var3'] = 0;

    /* do something */
}
```

or in a more compact way:

```
public function __construct($bar)
{
    $bar = array_merge(array('var1' => 0, 'var2' => 0, 'var3' => 0), $bar);
    /* do something */
}
```

Comment: Shorter way of writing it without the `if`s: `$bar = array_merge(array('var1'=>0, 'var2'=>0, 'var3'=>0), $bar);`. But +1.

Answer (score 1):

```
class foo
{
    public function __construct($bar = array())
    {
        $bar += array(
            "var1" => 0,
            "var2" => 0,
            "var3" => 0
        );

        /* do something */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $bar = func_get_args();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot do that you should pass the array as a whole. also the keys have to be quoted

```
public function __construct($bar)
    {
        $bar['var1']  = 0;
        $bar['var2']  = 0;
        $bar['var3']  = 0;

        /* do something */
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class foo
{
    public function __construct($bar = array('var'=>0, 'var2'=>0, 'var3'=>0))
    {
        var_dump($bar);
    }
}
```